# Facebook JavaScript SDK with Build.Phonegap

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-build

thanks for reading and hopefully replying.

I am creating an application in Build.Phonegap and focusing on publishing it to the Google Play Store. I am writing it in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I have added the Facebook JavaScript SDK for Login, Like, and Share buttons. When I access the project through Parse.com where i have it hosted for browsers, it renders as i expect it to with all the buttons appearing and functioning correctly (I assume my code is correct from this). BUT when I zip the file and download the APK using the QRcode on Build.Phonegap, I see some HTML *but no JavaScript relating to the Facebook SDK.*
At the beginning of signing up via Facebook I selected to be a Facebook Developer for a Website, not an Android application.

**My Question is - Should I register as a Facebook Developer for Android to get Android-related APP ID and App Secret even though I am coding via HTML,CSS & JS? Would this help my Android phone read the JS?**

I have read from a Build.Phonegap employee that the 3rd party plugin isn't needed for Facebook JS, so that not my problem.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated even if it stimulates a lightbulb moment!

Comment: "Should I register as a Facebook Developer for Android to get Android-related APP ID and App Secret even though I am coding via HTML,CSS & JS? Would this help my Android phone read the JS?" Yes. This is still a native application and needs to be handled as a native application.